# How to execute @SqlCondition dynamically in this situation?

Tags: sql-server

I have to execute `@sqlcondition` parameter as dynamic as well as sometimes it's appended to other queries. How can this be done?

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].MyProfile_Duplicate   
  @PageNum = 1,
  @PageSize = 50,
  @BreakDownTypeText = N'List',
  @CapOrderCount = NULL,
  @typeofCaporder = NULL,
  @PivotColname = NULL,
  @TableName = N'data',
  @BreakdownCondition = NULL,
  @Distance = NULL,
  @ZipCode = NULL,
  @SqlCondition =N'''SELECT LastSeen,MSACode, Age ,count (1) as TotalSearchCount FROM tablename  WHERE (year IN (''+(Select year FROM yeardata where addressno=1246)+''))  
and  1=1 group by LastSeen,MSACode, Age'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Finally Answer is got to my Question 

DECLARE @SqlCondition Nvarchar(max);
SET @SqlCondition ='Declare @query nvarchar(max); SET @query=';
SET @SqlCondition +=N'''SELECT LastSeen,MSACode, Age ,count (1) as TotalSearchCount FROM tablename  WHERE (year IN (''+(Select year FROM yeardata where addressno=1246)+''))  
                       and  1=1 group by LastSeen,MSACode, Age'''
SET @SqlCondition +=';EXEC sp_executesql @query';

EXEC(@SqlCondition);
```

Comment: I will modify @sqlcondition parameter  in stored procedure by appending as like above format